# How to declare "using" for "std::array" using template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, std, stdarray

For example I have code like:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
using Map = std::map<A, B>;

template<typename A, typename B>
using UnorderedMap = std::unordered_map<A, B>;
```

I would like to do the same thing for `std::array`, i.e:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
using Array = std::array<A, B>;
```

But if I do this, I will get a compiler error:

> error C2993: 'B': illegal type for non-type template parameter '_Size'
>
> error C2955: 'std::array': use of class template requires template
>
> argument list array(21): message : see declaration of 'std::array'

Is there any way to declare an `Array` that would in the background be using the `std::array`?

In the end I want to use arrays like `Array<int, 7> items` instead of `std::array<int, 7> items`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 2nd template parameter of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) with type `std::size_t`. It should be

```
template<typename A, std::size_t B>
using Array = std::array<A, B>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, second template argument of `std::array` is not a type but a `size_t` so the syntax should be

```
                     vvvvvv

template<typename T, size_t S>
using Array = std::array<T, S>;
```